# How to grab stock data from Quandl with tickers that have a full stop? Python

Tags: python, pandas, quandl, pandas-datareader

Due to Python's pandas_datareader API no longer being able to extract Yahoo finance stock data, I'm using quandl. This requires setting up an account and doing a 'pip install quandl' in the command terminal.
If I have an unusual stock ticker, like say BRK.B, using the pandas_datareader API to extract stock data from Google works perfectly fine.

```
 import pandas as pd
 import datetime
 from pandas_datareader import data, wb
 start = datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 1)
 end = datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1)
 brk = data.DataReader("BRK.B", "google", start, end)["Close"]
 brk
```

However, this won't work with quandl due to the stock ticker, BRK.B having a full-stop inside it.

```
 import quandl
 brk = ["BRK.B"]
 for stk in brk:
     b = quandl.get("WIKI/{}".format(stk),
         authtoken = "Mixture of numbers, and lower/upper case letters",
         start, end)["Adj. Close"]
```

This causes the code to break. However, if I swap ["BRK.B"] for any normal stock ticker, say ["AAPL"], it works perfectly fine.
I'd like to extract all 505 stock from the S&P 500 using the quandl API, however, because some stock tickers have a "." in them, it won't work.
I've tried `format(stk.replace(".", "-"))` and that didn't work either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. BTW, for those who don't know. You have to set up a quandl account, then get your API key code from your quandl account settings, then copy and paste it as your authtoken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to replace it with underscore maybe?

```
"WIKI/{}".format(stk.replace(".", "_"))  # replacing . with _ instead of -
```

If I remember correctly, dot is used to slice the specific column from data.

Comment: Hi errata, sorry, not quite sure what you're saying. Any code would be easier for me to read. Try the code yourself, just make sure you have a quandl account set up, and can get your authtoken from your quandl account setting.

Comment: @MichaelRSF Updated my answer. I don't have Quandl account anymore but I was using it briefly a while ago...

Comment: Thank you very much errata, my bad. I should have read your message properly. With pandas_datareader using "yahoo", it would have been `stk.replace(".", "-")`. I'm using quandl because I need the adjusted closing prices, and pandas_datareader with "google" only gives the closing prices, which is less accurate because adjusted closing prices take into account all transaction costs, dividends, etc.

Comment: @MichaelRSF I didn't quite understand did replacing with underscore helped or not? :) I remember I had to do something similar, but cannot quite remember what exactly and whether was it with stock ticker in the first place :/